# C# DataGridView FullRowSelect and Double Click Event

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

i created a DataGridView and enable FullRowSelect in the Properties, now i want to check if a user double click on a row (not the header) but the cellContentDoubleClick Event dont fired up. I dont understand why ?

Comment: I actually bothered to try the combination of *FullRowSelect* & *CellContentDoubleClick* and the event fired correctly. Are you entirely sure about what's casuing the event not to get fired?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to catch double click event and `FullRowSelect` is enabled use `DoubleClick` event and not `cellContentDoubleClick` :

```
private void dataGridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var RowsIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;

    MessageBox.Show("THE INDEX OF THE ROW THAT WAS DOUBLE CLICKED: " + RowsIndex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Why do you even bother to answer? A comment is way enough for this small piece of information. There is just one thing I can think of why someone would still post the information as an answer but not as a comment...that's not my downvote though. Not to get you upset or whatever.

Comment: The [DoubleClick event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.doubleclick(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't return any information about the row which was double-clicked.

Comment: @stuartd please see my updated answer